# Failed to Parse string to float in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, floating-point

I want to convert the following string to `"5,28"` to `float` number, I used this code but I got false result. Also I'm setting the device language to french.

Is there something I'm missing? I have tried to convert the string to different culture like `CultureInfo("en-US")` but still did not work.

```
bool result = float.TryParse("5,28", NumberStyles.Float,
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out number);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) uses `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) not `,`

Since you forced to use `Float` style, this style includes *only* `AllowDecimalPoint` in a separator styles, your method thinks this `,` is a decimal separator but `InvariantCulture` does not use it. That's why you get exception.

There are a few things you can do. One option can be [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) an `InvariantCulture`, set `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to `,` and use *that* cloned culture in your `TryParse` method.

```
float f;
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
var result = float.TryParse("5,28", NumberStyles.Float, clone, out f); // true
```

Or you can use a culture that *already* has `,` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` like `tr-TR` culture.<sup>1</sup>

```
float f;
var result = float.TryParse("5,28", NumberStyles.Float, 
                                    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"), out f); // true
```

<sup>1</sup>:Since I'm from Turkey :)

Comment: So the solution to OP's question is "replace the ',' in your string with a '.'".

Comment: @Kevin That can be as well but we can't know where this string comes from. What if it is an input from outside, right? Replacing separators in a string _usually_ a bad idea.

Comment: @Kevin Yes but these kind of answers do not encourage learning.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the value `5,28` does not parse is that invariant culture uses decimal dot `.`, not decimal comma.

To solve this problem you could either replace comma with a dot, like this

```
bool result=float.TryParse(
    "5.28"
,   NumberStyles.Float
,   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat
,   out number);
```

or replace `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for a culture that uses comma in place of a dot:

```
bool result=float.TryParse(
    "6,78"
,   NumberStyles.Float
,   new CultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat
,   out number);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/tk1GAx)